# How do I manage multiple data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have this table for an online reservation school project:

[image: SQL Table]

I was just wondering what if a student decided to reserve two items (uniform), how would I manage to fit it into one reservation number (primary key) if I can only put one item at a time?

Comment: If you can reserve more than one item on a particular reservation you have a one to many relationship, so you should store this in a separate table, e.g. `reserveration_item`, with a foreign key back to the reservation table

Answer (score 1):

You should move the **Uniform** objects into a separate table which is in relation with the current table so that there will be a single **Reservation** with multiple **Uniforms** related to it. The relation between this two tables can be a **Foreign Key** from the uniform table to the reservation table.

[Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I do have a Uniform table, does that mean my Reservation table can accommodate multiple Foreign Keys from the Uniform table?

Comment: By accommodate multiple FK from Uniform table do you mean multiple Uniform rows/records refering to the same Reservation row/record? If so the answear is yes it can be accomplished.